# Python Progressbar2 - Slowing down program?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. I am using progressbar to show how long a task is taking. This is the code I have wrapped around a to_excel command:

```
dfPub = pd.DataFrame(aPub)

    if dfPub.empty:
        print("There are no Publications")
    else:
        with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=10) as bar:
            for i in range(10):
                dfPub.to_excel(writer, 'Publications', columns=cols, index=False)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                bar.update(i)
```

It is working, but when testing with and without there is a massive difference in time it is taking to run i.e. without the progressbar, it takes about 2-3 seconds, and with it is taking around 15 seconds.

Am I implementing it incorrectly?

Comment: are you using `time.sleep(0.1)` without the Progressbar ?

Comment: Hey, no I am not. I am guessing that is slowing it down. I thought it was needed, can I drop it?

Comment: yope, drop that sleepy line

Comment: Ok, dropped it and it still slowing it down. I ran a smaller test and it was pretty much 1-2 seconds without and 6 seconds with it. I am mighty confused!

Answer (score 1):

use multi-threading method, with threading module, put your progressbar on a  new thread and test it again, you can read more on : https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

Comment: Thank you. I have never heard of threading before. I will look into it now to see how I can make my code work with it. I will report back. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think this may take me a while. I will vote up your answer, and if later I can get it working, ill mark your answer as correct :).... ty